# scheduling a laravel command

Tags: laravel, cron, task, schedule

So a while back I built an app for a company and now they'd like it revised a bit.  The basis of the app is an RSVP system for health care Seminars and Consultations.  They would now like to send email and text reminders once daily for to all clients whose seminar/consultation is within 24 hours.  So I've created the code to pull all the seminars/consultations that occur within 24 hours.  I know I will need to set up a CRON job on their server, which is not a big deal, but how would you go about the scheduling?  Am I better off creating 2 new commands (one for seminars, one for consultations) and using the `$schedule->command('some:newCommand --force)->dailyAt(2:00);` in the Kernel.php file, or would you just `$schedule->command('queue:work --force)->dailyAt(2:00);` . I'm just trying to understand best/most efficient practice.

Comment: This is, ultimately, up to you. I like to have my commands do one thing; if sending a seminar notification uses the same code as sending a consultation notification, I'd make it one task. If they're totally different code, I'd do two commands.

Comment: Why are you thinking of using `queue:work`? It's used to run queued jobs and it's supposed to be run in a long-lived (think: permanent) process.

Comment: Well the thing is there could anywhere from 0-200 emails/text that may need to be sent.  So I guess I'm curious as how you would dispatch the jobs and or event/listeners?  I mean what makes sense to me is grab my data, then loop through and on each iteration of the loop dispatch the job.  Is that best practice?

Answer (score 1):

Just my 2 cents...

1. use $schedule->job(...) instead
2. put que:work in a supervised process
3. The schedule->job will figure out all the messages that need sending and make 1 job per message transmission.  So, a job that makes more jobs.
4. Use the failed_jobs table to track if anyone didn't get the message.

Comment: So what you're saying is that I should make a main job and then from that job, dispatch the secondary jobs (email/text) for each client?

Comment: Ya, that's just what I'd do - because  I'd want to see the failed jobs.